# Add a refunding function (and a warning that there are no stocks left) in my vending machine project in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The stock number decreases by one every time a user chooses and buys a soda.

However, if the user keeps on buying on the same code ("A1" in this case) but there are no stocks left, money still subtracts by a certain amount.

How do I warn the user that there are no more stocks left for "A1" and how do I let the user know their money will be refunded?

```js
//Soda Choice with If-Then Statements
sodaChoice.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var sodaChoice = window.prompt("Select your code.");
      console.log(sodaChoice);

      if (sodaChoice == "A1") {
        window.alert("You selected Coca-Cola.");
        window.alert("This costs $" + sodaPrice[0] + "."); //sodaprice[0] calls the first element in "sodaPrice's" array
        window.alert(sodaPrice[0] <= $money ? "You have enough. Have a nice day." : "You don't have enough. Try again.");
        $money -= sodaPrice[0].toFixed(2);
        console.log("You now have " + $money.toFixed(2));
        while (stockCocaCola !== 0) {
          stockCocaCola--;
          break; //The break function stops this while loop from rapidly subtracting stockCocaCola by 1 until stockCocaCola reaches 0.
        }
        console.log("Stock left for Coca-Cola: " + stockCocaCola);
      }
```

Comment: that's because stockCocaCola !== 0 this condition is checked after the money is deducted. Move all the logic inside only is there is stock available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of refunding, I would deduct money only if the stock is available, else give alert message. (Removed while loop too as it's not required)

```
//Soda Choice with If-Then Statements
 sodaChoice.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var sodaChoice = window.prompt("Select your code.");
  console.log(sodaChoice);

  if (sodaChoice == "A1") {
    window.alert("You selected Coca-Cola.");
    window.alert("This costs $" + sodaPrice[0] + "."); //sodaprice[0] calls the first element in "sodaPrice's" array
    window.alert(sodaPrice[0] <= $money ? "You have enough. Have a nice day." : "You don't have enough. Try again.");
    if(stockCocaCola > 0) {
      $money -= sodaPrice[0].toFixed(2);
      console.log("You now have " + $money.toFixed(2));
      stockCocaCola--;
    }
    else{
      window.alert("No Stock available for " + sodaChoice );
    }
    console.log("Stock left for Coca-Cola: " + stockCocaCola);
  }
```